# Understanding Euler's proof of infinity of primes

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation

Here is the proof verbatim, supposed to be from Euler:

> Let $\pi(x) := \#\{p\le x: p \in \mathbb P\}$ be the number of primes
> that are less than or equal to the real number $x$. We number the
> primes $\mathbb P = \{ p_1, p_2, p_3...\}$ in increasing order. Consider the
> natural logarithm $\log x$, defined as $\log x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} dt$.
>
> Now we compare the area below the graph of $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}$ with an
> upper step function. Thus for $n\le x < n+1$ we have
>
> $$\log x \le 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 ... \frac1n + \frac{1}{n+1}$$
> $$\log x \le \sum \frac1m$$ Where the sum extends over all
> $m\in\mathbb{N}$ which have only prime divisors $p\le x$.
>
> Since every $m$ can be written in a *unique* way as a product of the
> form $\prod\limits_{p\le x}p^{k_p}$, we see that the last sum is equal
> to $$\prod\limits_{p\in \mathbb P, p\le x}\left(\sum\limits_{k\ge 0}\frac{1}{p^k}\right)$$ The inner sum is a geometric series with a
> ratio $\frac{1}{p}$, hence $$\log x \le \prod\limits_{p\in \mathbb P,
> p\le x}\frac{p}{p-1} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{p_k}{p_k-1}$$
> Now clearly, $p_k\ge k+1$, and thus $$\log x \le
>  \prod\limits_{k=1}^{\pi(x)}\frac{k + 1}{k} = \pi(x) +1$$ Since $\log
> x$ is not bounded, we conclude that $\pi(x)$ is not bounded, and hence
> there are infinitely many primes

### In short

Basically, I do not understand many steps in the proof, mainly the jump from $\frac1m$ onwards, where the sum of the $\frac1m$ was broken down into a product of a sum of reciprocals of primes.

### Specific

I do not understand the following:

1. *Where the sum extends over all $m\in\mathbb{N}$ which have only prime divisors $p\le x$.* Why is this so? Shouldn't this include only a very small subset of such $m$, and not *all* of them?
2. What does $p^{k_p}$ mean in when we say that each of the $m$ can be represented as a product of such powers of different $p$. What I understood is that $k_p$ is the power which appears with $p$ in the prime factorization of $m$. But if this is so, then I absolutely fail to understand the next step (*3.*)
3. I do not understand how we could keep the product outside the sum. And here, why is the $k_p$ in the former step reduced to $k$?

### My attempt

I tried pondering over this for quite a while, as well as looking at other sites on the net if they may present a more descriptive and less concise proof for this. But I failed to find any.

Comment: Distribute the multiplication of the product of sums of powers of primes. How does it work the distributive law? You form all possible products choosing one term from each factor. But each selection is a unique power of a unique prime. Compare that to the unique representation of a natural number as a product of powers of primes.

Comment: You can try a small example: $(1+1/2+1/2^2+...)(1+1/3+1/3^2+1/3^3+...)=1+1/2+1/3+1/2^2+1/(2\cdot 3)+1/3^2+1/2^3+1/(2^2\cdot 3)+1/(2\cdot 3^2)+1/3^3+...$

Comment: By the way, Question (1) is only noticing that since $n\leq x$ all the numbers $1,2,...,n$ are $\leq x$ and therefore all their prime factors are also $\leq x$. The sum becomes even larger if you add more terms. Namely, all the terms corresponding to all the numbers with prime factors $\leq x$.

Comment: @user647486 Okay, I get some parts, but am still confused about the $k_p$ and $k$ notation. Can you write the comments as an answer?

Comment: Your description of what $k_p$ means is correct. They have nothing to do with the $k$ in the next line, which is only the dummy variable of the sum taking the values $0,1,2,...$. The jump from between those two lines is the observation that I made in the first two comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention is to show that $\log x \le \pi(x) + 1$. This only makes sense for $x > 0$.

For $x \le e$ it is trivial since $\log x \le 1$. Thus, in the following considerations we may assume $x \ge 1$. We have
$$\log x = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}dt < \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{t}dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \int_m^{m+1} \frac{1}{t}dt < \sum_{m=1}^n \int_m^{m+1} \frac{1}{m}dt = \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m}$$
which corrects the formula in your question.

Let $\mathbb P (x)$ denote the set of primes $\le x$ and $\mathbb N (x)$ the set of integers all of whose prime divisors are in $\mathbb P (x)$. Each $m \in \mathbb N (x)$ has a unique representation $m = \prod_{p \in \mathbb P (x)} p^{k_p(m)}$ with $k_p(m) \in \mathbb N \cup \{ 0 \}$.

Since $n \le x < n+1$, all $m \le n$ belong to $\mathbb N (x)$ and we obtain
$$\sum_{m=1}^{n} \frac{1}{m} \le \sum_{m \in \mathbb N (x)} \frac{1}{m} .$$
Note that the sum on the right hand side is infinite. That it converges will be seen in the sequel.

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^k}$ is a geometric series converging absolutely to $\frac{p}{p -1}$. It is well-known that the product of absolutely convergent series can be written as an absolutely convergent series (see e.g.  [Product of absolutely convergent series is absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2147746)). Writing $\mathbb P (x) = \{p_1,\dots,p_r \}$, we obtain
$$\prod_{p \in \mathbb P (x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^k} = \prod_{i=1}^r\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p_i^k} = \sum_{s=0}^\infty d_s$$
with
$$d_s = \sum_{k_1,\dots,k_r \ge 0 \text{ with } k_1 + \dots + k_r = s} \prod _{i=1}^r \frac{1}{p_i^{k_i}} .$$
Therefore
$$\prod_{p \in \mathbb P (x)}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{p^k} = \sum_{k_1,\dots,k_r \ge 0} \prod _{i=1}^r \frac{1}{p_i^{k_i}} = \sum_{m \in \mathbb N (x)} \frac{1}{m} .$$
This shows that the series on the right hand side is absolutely convergent to $\prod_{p \in \mathbb P (x)} \frac{p}{p -1}$.